# Sending Email using mobile application

Tags: javascript, email, drupal, jquery-mobile, drupal-6

I want to send email to xyz@gmail.com from my jQuery mobile app which is a phonegap project.how it is possible using ajax,js and jQuery mobile??
I want to implement 'feedback' function using this.User should able send title(Product name) and body(feedback) to xyz@gmail.com from his/her mobile.

i am using drupal6 for all my services so please tell me how to access drupal api to send mail using javascript

Thank you..!

Comment: You just need a server to process the mail

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your feedback form to a server-side script:

HTML --

```
<form data-ajax="false">
   ...
</form>
```

The `data-ajax="false"` is so jQuery Mobile does not handle the form submission on its own.

JS --

```
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'http://myserver.com/myscript.php',

        //add the forms input namv/value pairs to the AJAX request
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function (serverResponse) { /*Here you can confirm the message was sent to the user*/ },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*Don't forget to handler errors*/ }
    });

    //stop the form from submitting normally
    return false;
});
```

PHP --

```
//create a message to send
$message = "Title: " . $_GET['title'] . "\n" .
           "Body: " . $_GET['body'];

//send the message
mail('xyz@gmail.com', 'App Feedback', $message);
```

Since you are using PhoneGap, you can get the device's unique ID or version information and append it to your form submission.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#Device

Comment: my application is accessing drupal6  for all services, so please tell me how to use drupal api mail function using javascript at my mobile app